# Query related to build skills set in Python

Tags: python

I am a B.Tech. 3rd year Student.I have learned Python and i want to build my text stack in python.
I want to know that what are the technologies related to python that i can learn to upskill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that you need to learn pandas and numpy first
you can learn them from here :

[1](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/): [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/)

[numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/)

then you should learn how to use database in python i recommend you to use SQLite:

[SQLite in python](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/)

then you can findout what you need next. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Basically python is widely known due to his available libraries available and due to his simplicity to write code.
To upskill yourself in the field if python there are various tools and technologies available some of them are:

Python Web Frameworks :

Python have some web frameworks which are highly used for development of a full stack website such as Django web Framework , Flask ,etc

Machine Learning:

Python is widely used in machine Learning due to the libraries available you can learn those libraries to learn Machine Learning and earn more and more. some of the libraries used like Numpy, Pandas , Scikit learn, Tensorflow ,etc.

Mobile Development:

python has a very good scope in mobile app development because it reduces the complexity . Learn libraries used for python mobile app development.